# Which four letters?

Tags: riddle

- I'm supposed to remember, but I'll quickly forget.
- Removing the first letter doesn't change much, but you get an animal.
- The first two letters are admirable; the last two are old-school tunes.
- Take away third letter, and the two will miss each other.
- Once you've got me, you'll notice me hidden in plain sight.
- Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> dram

Which four letters?

> Clearly four letters

I'm supposed to remember, but I'll quickly forget.

> D ram is volatile memory, which means it forgets when the power supply is removed.

Removing the first letter doesn't change much, but you get an animal.

> Ram still refers to random access memory, and it's also an animal

The first two letters are admirable; the last two are old-school tunes.

> Dr. is an honorable title. AM radio

Take away third letter, and the two will miss each other.

> DRM stands for Digital Rights Management. I guess you miss your copyrighted music.

Once you've got me, you'll notice me hidden in plain sight.

> Your username

Comment: Yes it was a mistake... sorry

Comment: You can try searching the three letters, though

Comment: @dram I'm still not entirely sure what the "missing" refers to. Did I get it right now?

Comment: that's about right, I was talking about it commonly being *hfrq ba zhfvp*, hence *erfgevpgvat lbhe npprff*